# Como priorizar a conexão wifi do dispositivo mesmo sem internet?

Tags: android, apache-cordova, redes

Tenho uma aplicação (Android/iOS) que roda em uma rede wifi local (que não possui internet).

Por esta rede wifi não possuir internet, os dispositivos priorizam o 3G/4G, e assim minha aplicação (API local) acaba não funcionando.

Já tentei procurar se existia alguma forma de programaticamente desabilitar os dados móveis do dispositivo, porém sem sucesso pois a Google e Apple não permitem isso.

Hoje, como alternativa, apenas mostro um botão para o usuário entrar nas configurações do dispositivo, que acho uma boa solução, mas não a melhor no meu caso, porque meu público alvo são pessoas idosas que possuem muitas dificuldades em operar o dispositivo.

O que eu gostaria é que de alguma forma não precisasse entrar nas configurações do dispositivo. Sei que meu cenário é complicado, mas será que existe alguma alternativa?

Obs: é obrigatório a rede wifi não possuir internet, a maioria do público são idosos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tranquilo de fazer isso.
vc precisa ter na sua rede wifi, um servidor web que responda as solicitações do android e da apple.

Todos os dispositivos (smartphones, computadores, dispositivos que acessam a internet) fazem uma requisição http para uma determinada url para saber se tem ou não internet na rede, a mesma requisição é usada para identificar quanto tem um portal captivo (que pede cadastros para liberar internet, como os que tem em aeroportos), mas a diferença do portal captivo é que ele faz um redirect na solicitação http 302, e oque vc precisa é de um servidor web (local) que responda essas requisições

Como exemplo deixo para vc a url que um dispositivo Apple faz a solicitação 
[http://captive.apple.com/][1] a resposta é **Success**

Código html da resposta:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Success</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>Success</BODY></HTML>
```

EDIT: vc vai precisar dos seguintes serviços rodando no mesmo. Web, PHP e DNS, além do básico.

> 1 - Vc deve configurar o servidor de DNS para distribuir ip na sua rede interna e apontando como servidor de DNS ele mesmo, pois é ele que irá resolver os domínios pesquisados, apontando para o endereço ip da maquina que irá responder as solicitações HTTP, no caso ele mesmo.
>
> 2 - Vc deve criar um virtual host em seu servidor web para entregar a página index.php

Conteúdo da página index.php para responder 200(tem internet), e mantém a conexão dos dispositivos.

```
<?php
    header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
?>
```

Com essa resposta, todos dispositivos android ou apple vão se manter conectados a rede wifi, pq eles acharam que tem internet.

Comment: Alessandro, teria algum exemplo de como montar esse servidor?

Comment: @LennonS.Bueno editei minha resposta, e acrescentei um exemplo para vc. A ideia e vc pesquisar para conseguir fazer, mas conforme sua dificuldade posso ir dando umas dicas aos poucos.